# UK Standard Visitor Visa refused for my spouse because she couldn't demonstrate herself as a genuine visitor. What are my options?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, spouses

I am currently in UK on ICT Tier 2 VISA for 6 months. My wife (housewife) applied for general visit Visa in March 2015, to join me and for tourism purpose for 4 months. She intended to leave Uk with me in July 2015.

But her visa was rejected, here is the exact reason stated: "*You intend to travel to UK to join your husband. You have provided no information regarding thee purpose of your proposed visit other than to join him. I note that your husband has applied for VISA for duration of 6 months. I note that you are supported by your husband in India"
"There is a category of visa that allows a spouse to join a migrant whoo has tier 2 employment visa. I am not satisfied that you are merely joining you husband as dependant."
"As you have provided no information regarding thee purpose of your proposed visit other than joining your husband, I do not consider you are travelling to Uk for tourism purpose. I am not satisfied that you will leave UK at the end of the proposed visit*"

I note that, she had not provided any air tickets for her travel; neither she had submitted travel itineary. We were planning to book the air tickets after VISA arrival. I guess the Visa application was for general visit, but somehow represented as dependant visa.

Can anyone please tell me, what we missed here and can she apply again immediately? Is this a big issue? Or She can get visa again if she corrects the missing things? Do we have to plan and book the hotels in advance and show the hotel bookings as travel plan? Its really difficult to plan and book hotels for holidays in future.

Please help with your suggestions and inputs if any. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you provide evidence of the reasons why she would return ?

Comment: Thanks @GayotFow . I have added the exact text in my query. Thanks for help.

Comment: @DumbCoder No I didnt provide any evidence of reasons of her return. She is housewife, what can be submitted as evidence please suggest. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

The UK decision-making process for visitors does not acknowledge purchased flight tickets as evidence and they do not refuse applicants on that basis.  This is a difference from the Schengen decision-making process where confirmed arrangements are needed.  There has been an advisory on the the UK site recommending that the applicant **NOT** purchase tickets in advance of an approval.

They *already know* for example that tickets can be refunded or even abandoned.  Confirmations can be forged.  They *also know* that a person who wants to abuse a visa (or overstay, or deal drugs, etc) can quite easily purchase tickets.  In fact, anybody with a credit card can purchase air tickets, but what does it prove?  Moreover, they *already know* about all the tricks one finds on the internet about printing off confirmations and cancelling them or other ways to game the airline reservation systems.  So the bottom line is that they will ignore purchased air tickets as evidence.  If anything, it's harmful because it shows you did not read the guidance.

Reading the text from your refusal notice helps to clarify the ECO's grounds for your wife's refusal, namely that she did not appear to be a genuine visitor.  Instead, she appeared to be a person joining a spouse who was in the UK on a Tier 2 Inter-company transfer (T2 ICT).  This is a different category of visa with different terms and conditions.  Based upon all that's given, she simply applied in the wrong category.

For your last question, your wife can submit a fresh application any time, and there is no 'cooling off' period between successive applications.  However, she should *not* apply as a visitor because the ECO made it clear that she cannot qualify in that category.  Instead, she should apply as a T2 dependent.

You can ask more questions about that kind of application at https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions

**Adding...**

This answer applies to people who must apply for [entry clearance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/what-is-entry-clearance-ecb03) at a foreign [issuing post](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NEdtAR3q8eIC&pg=PA260&lpg=PA260&dq=entry%20clearance%20issuing%20post&source=bl&ots=uA3QUslFs9&sig=p7YcYTfS5vAOhRTXBXQN-iTU6S0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nbAxVfCAE46vaf3FgdAK&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=entry%20clearance%20issuing%20post&f=false) outside the UK.  People who can come to the UK "on their passport" will always need to show tickets because they are *already here*.  Different rules apply in those cases.

---

## Update 25 April 2015

The new [guidance published yesterday](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf) states explicitly that they **DO NOT** want to see hotel bookings and flight bookings.  Their intent is to eliminate a long-standing public confusion about it.  The original answer is not changed, but there's now clarity in the guidance.

---